# Why cann't I use snmptable to search a mib table in net-snmp?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpwalk

I know this oid is a table from the web, so I try to use snmptable,but it return wrong.

scEnclFanTable  1.3.6.1.4.1.674.11000.2000.500.1.2.20

```
snmptable -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.10 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.11000.2000.500.1.2.20
```

[image]

When I use walk,the result is ok? What wrong with my command?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is rather clear on that,

> Also, **snmptable relies on having the relevant MIB file available (and loaded), in order to know which columns to retrieve. It is not possible to run it without this MIB - even if numeric OIDs are used (which would otherwise be fine)**:

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable

In your case, you didn't load the relevant MIB documents, so `snmptable` fails as expected.

Comment: Actually the system has load the MIB,beacuse I can search the data using snmpwalk.May be scEnclFanTable is a table ,but it is not a MIB table?

Comment: @flower, no. If the relevant MIB documents are properly loaded, you won't see so many numbers but their corresponding textual names.